# Spring JdbcTemplate , How to dynamically set username and password in Spring config XML file?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Spring JDBC:  while using JdbcTemplate how to set username and password for every user ?, Currently I am Configuring datasource object as a spring bean (Spring config.xml file ) and able to login with sinlge username and password , also used properties file and placeholder for the same

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apu"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value=""></property>
</bean>
```

What are the ways to set username value and password value for every user who logsin ?
This is my first Spring application hence not able to find right approach ..

Comment: Take a look at the [`UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.html). However be aware that this basically destroys the ability to use a connection pool as each user requires its own connection. Make sure that this is what you really want (and need!).

Comment: @M.Deinum : Thanks Deinum , Need your guideline pls, Using Spring jdbc template and spring config.xml file I am able to access a DB2 based Stored Procedure giving my username and password  , Now I want to make it access to more than one user ? what would be the best approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in a web application, each user do not use its own identity to access the database. The common pattern is to have one single database user for the application, and let the application manage the permission of its own users.

As M.Deinum said, this pattern allows the application to use a connection pool, where database connections are recycled across different requests which dramatically reduces the database load (establishment of the connection is expensive)

If you look at (almost) all the spring examples an tutorial, they consitently use that approach with one single database user for the whole web application.

If you really need that each user uses it own database identity you must use a [UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.html) as suggested by M. Deinum, with no database pool.